# For loop that checks if a string contains symbols?

Tags: java

I was working on a program that asks the user to input the name of a variable, and the program checks to see if it uses good style, is legal but poor style, or is completely illegal. For the purposes of this program, good style means that the variable only uses letters and digits, and only begins with a lowercase letter. The program does not have to check if the second, third, or etc word in the variable name begins with a capital letter. I have spent the past few days or so trying to figure out  how to get the for loop to check each character in the variable name to see if it is a symbol, and I have not been able to. Any help would be appreciated, and if you are down voting this question, please tell me why so I can make my questions better in the future :)
Here is the code that I have at the moment. It does not compile; it says char cannot be dereferenced, but I do not need anyone to rewrite the code for me. I only need people to tell me how they would go about trying to check the variable name for symbols.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VariableNameChecker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String variableName;
        int count;
        char ch;
        String status = "good";

        System.out.print("This program checks the properness of a proposed Java variable name.");
        System.out.print("\nEnter a variable name (q to quit): ");
        variableName = sc.next();

        for(count = 0; count < variableName.length(); count++) //check each character of variableName to see if it is good style
        {
            ch = variableName.charAt(count);
            if (ch == ' ')
            {
                status = "bad";
            }
            else if (ch.isDigit || ch.isUpperCase || ch == '_')
            {
                status = "poor";
            }
        }
        if (status.equals("bad"))
        {
            System.out.print("Illegal.");
        }
        else if (status.equals("poor"))
        {
            System.out.print("Poor style");
        }
        else //variableName only contains letters and digits, and only begins with a lowercase letter
        {
            System.out.print("Good!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your expected output and the observed output. From what I see, you are missing a condition: if the status is already `bad`, you must not set it to `poor`. Basically, if the status is `bad`, you can exit the loop.

Comment: Does it have to be a for loop or would you be happy with regex, too?

Comment: This code does not compile. `char` is a primitive type and has no methods making `ch.isDigit` and `ch.isUpperCase` illegal calls. You should use `Character.isDigit(ch)` and `Character.isUpperCase(ch)` instead.

Comment: I know that it does not compile at the moment. I was trying to figure out the bulk of it on my own, and just wanted to know how one would check if a string contains a character other than a letter or digit. It does not have to be a for loop either, but that is what I was recommended to use, and I just cannot figure out how to use one in this scenario. Thanks again!!

Comment: @IronMaiden28 this is critical information. When you have compiler errors, please say so and post the compiler error message in your question.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question. Sorry about that!! I didn't necessarily want anyone to rewrite my code, just tell me how I would go about checking the variableName for symbols @Turing85

Comment: @IronMaiden28 check Ivaylo Toskov's comment. There is everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the whole line from the `Scanner`. Otherwise you `Scanner` will tokenize your input from all the white spaces.

Use can use your `status` variable for final printing too. No need to add other `if-else` statements.

You have to loop your code in a infinite loop so that you can prompt more values. If you want to quit, you can use `q` as you stated.

I tried an example. It can be helpful..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String variableName;
    String status;
    boolean firstTime;

    System.out.print("This program checks the properness of a proposed Java variable name.");

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a variable name (q to quit): ");
        status = "Good!";
        variableName = sc.nextLine();
        if (variableName.equals("q")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        firstTime = true;
        for (char ch : variableName.toCharArray()) //check each character of variableName to see if it is good style
        {
            if (Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(ch)) {
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
                    if (firstTime) {
                        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                            status = "Illegal";
                            break;
                        }
                        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                            status = "Poor Style";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    status = "Poor Style";
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                status = "Illegal";
                break;
            }
            firstTime = false;
        }
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! @Ramesh-X
What does toCharArray do?

Comment: It converts a given `String` to a `char` array. Then `for-each` loop is used to access character by character from the array. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

Comment: Ok, and what does Character.isJavaIdentifierPart do? @Ramesh-X

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart(char)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression for that:

1. start from lower case char ^[a-z]
2. only alphanumeric [a-zA-Z0-9]*

So, finally, you need to check on this regex: "^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VariableNameChecker {

private static final String MATCH_REGEX = "^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String variableName;
        String status = "good";

        System.out.print("This program checks the properness of a proposed Java variable name.");
        System.out.print("\nEnter a variable name (q to quit): ");
        variableName = sc.next();
        if (!variableName.matches(MATCH_REGEX)) {
            status = "bad";
        }
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```